Was Jesus a Jew at all?
First of all: what I mean here by “Jew” is nationality/race and not religion. The question of whether Jesus was a Jew therefore means whether Jesus was an Israeli, i.e. a descendant of Jacob/Israel. The focus here is not on whether Jesus was a Jew from a religious point of view, i.e. whether he was a follower of Judaism.
Was Jesus a Jew at all? He had no Jewish father, he is not from Jewish sperm. According to the Bible, a child inherits the nationality from the father. Two examples: 1. The wife of Joseph was a Gentile (Egyptian), and with her he made two children, Ephraim and Manasseh. Although their mother was a Gentile, they are still called Israelis because their father was an Israeli. They inherited their father's nationality. 2. Moses allowed the men of Israel to take Gentile women, but he didn't allow them to take Gentile men for Israeli women.
Since Jesus did not come out of Jewish sperm, he can't be a Jew by nationality. It's wrong to say that Jesus was a "half-Jew" because his mother was a Jew. In the Bible, there is no such thing like "half". You are what your father is. If your father is Italian and your mother is Spanish, then you are Italian. You are not half-italian and half-spanish. You are what your father is because out of his sperm you came.
However, if someone wants to claim that the nationality goes from mother to child, then he must agree that Ephraim and Manasseh were not Israelis but Egyptians since their mother was Egyptian. He must also agree that Obed was not an Israeli but a Moabite since his mother Ruth was a Moabite. If he does not agree, then his position is hypocritical.
I have opened this topic in other communities but they have all been closed. I am opening this topic here now because Jesus also plays a major role in Islam and the question of his nationality is certainly not an unimportant issue for Muslims.
Since Jesus has no human father, he cannot biologically belong to any nationality. What does this mean now?

Jesus عليه السلام was a Muslim and not a Jew in religion, but he certainly was a descendant of Jacob (Israel) عليه السلام. Descendants include all children and their children and so on, both sons and daughters.
The Quran mentions Jesus, Abraham, Moses, Ishmael and Idrees عليهم السلام أجمعين and then says:

أولئك الذين أنعم الله عليهم من النبيين من ذرية آدم وممن حملنا مع نوح ومن ذرية إبراهيم وإسرائيل وممن هدينا واجتبينا إذا تتلى عليهم آيات الرحمن خروا سجدا وبكيا
Those were the ones upon whom Allah bestowed favor from among the prophets of the descendants of Adam and of those We carried [in the ship] with Noah, and of the descendants of Abraham and Israel, and of those whom We guided and chose. When the verses of the Most Merciful were recited to them, they fell in prostration and weeping.
— Quran 19:58

This proves that the mentioned prophets are all from the descendants of Adam and Noah and some are descendants of Abraham and Israel. If Jesus is a descendant of Adam then by he is also a descendant of Jacob as his line passed through him.
Similarly the Quran states:

ووهبنا له إسحاق ويعقوب كلا هدينا ونوحا هدينا من قبل ومن ذريته داوود وسليمان وأيوب ويوسف وموسى وهارون وكذلك نجزي المحسنين وزكريا ويحيى وعيسى وإلياس كل من الصالحين وإسماعيل واليسع ويونس ولوطا وكلا فضلنا على العالمين
And We gave to Abraham, Isaac and Jacob - all [of them] We guided. And Noah, We guided before; and among his descendants, David and Solomon and Job and Joseph and Moses and Aaron. Thus do We reward the doers of good. And Zechariah and John and Jesus and Elias - and all were of the righteous. And Ishmael and Elisha and Jonah and Lot - and all [of them] We preferred over the worlds.
— Quran 6:84-86

This means that Jesus is a descendant of Noah and\or Abraham and hence is a descendant of Jacob as well since his line passes through Jacob.
In its exegesis Ibn Kathir has written:

وفي ذكر " عيسى " ، - عليه السلام - ، في ذرية " إبراهيم " أو " نوح " ، على القول الآخر دلالة على دخول ولد البنات في ذرية الرجال ; لأن " عيسى " ، - عليه السلام - ، إنما ينسب إلى " إبراهيم " ، - عليه السلام - ، بأمه " مريم " - عليها السلام - ، فإنه لا أب له .
قال ابن أبي حاتم : حدثنا سهل بن يحيى العسكري ، حدثنا عبد الرحمن بن صالح ، حدثنا علي بن عابس ، عن عبد الله بن عطاء المكي ، عن أبي حرب بن أبي الأسود قال : أرسل الحجاج إلى يحيى بن يعمر فقال : بلغني أنك تزعم أن الحسن والحسين من ذرية النبي - صلى الله عليه وسلم - ، تجده في كتاب الله ، وقد قرأته من أوله إلى آخره فلم أجده؟ قال : أليس تقرأ سورة الأنعام : ( ومن ذريته داود وسليمان ) حتى بلغ ( ويحيى وعيسى ) ؟ قال : بلى ، قال : أليس عيسى من ذرية إبراهيم ، وليس له أب؟ قال : صدقت .
فلهذا إذا أوصى الرجل لذريته ، أو وقف على ذريته أو وهبهم ، دخل أولاد البنات فيهم
And the mention of Jesus  عليه السلام among the descendants of Abraham or Noah according to the second view (that the descendants here means descendants of Noah) proves that the descendants of a man's daughter are included in his descendants; because Jesus  عليه السلام only has a lineage to Abraham through his mother Mary عليها السلام for he has no father.
Ibn Abi Hatim has narrated that Hajjaj said to Yahya: I have heard that you claim that Hassan and Hussain are among the descendants of the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ and claim that this is found in the Quran. I have read the Quran from the beginning to end and I have not found this.
Yahya replied: Have you not read Surah al-'Anam: 'Among his descendants, David and Solomon ... and John and Jesus'?
Hajjad said: Yes
Yahya said: Is not Jesus from the descendants of Abraham although he has no father?
Hajjaj said: You are correct.
And it is because of this that if a person makes a bequest, endowment or a gift to his descendants then the children of his daughters are included in it
— Tafsir Ibn Kathir

As for the arguments in your post, I am not going to comment on whether they are right or not. What the current Bible says is not of any legal importance in Islam.

Ref:

Eesa (peace be upon him) was indisputably one of the Children of Israel.
— islamqa

